# What's the best RESTful URL structure for a recursive resource?

Tags: web-services

I'm creating a RESTfull service for a tree-like resource structure and was wondering what the best URL structure would be?

I have three requirements:

1. be able to get a collection of root
   resources
2. be able to get an
   individual resource
3. be able to get a
   collection of child resources

My current thought is:

```
/rest/documents
/rest/documents/{id}
/rest/documents/{id}/documents
```

I was also thinking of going the singular / plural routes to denote lists or individual elements, but I know I'm going to have a resource that is the same plural as it is singular, so decided against this.

Does anybody have any thoughts on the above? or have a different / better way of structuring this?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question but as we're talking about urls is SEO an issue?

Comment: SEO is not an issue, no. I'm basically asking the best logical URL structure for a self referencing resource.

Comment: That seems pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: How deep can that structure go?

Comment: @Martijn the depth is un-restricted

Comment: are nested resources "contained" in outer resources, or are the "referenced"?  Does it make sense to refer to a nested resource by an alternate name that doesn't include nesting?

Answer (score 12):

What comes to my mind is: do not let you RESTful API reflect the recursivity in the URL itself. Come to think of it, your resource is only the documents.

If you have your documents stored physically according to the recursive structure, create a mapping to an unique ID, and use the ID in the URL:

```
/rest/documents/{id}
```

Now, if you have your documents like this:

```
| DocumentName | DocumentPath | DocumentID |
--------------------------------------------
| abc          | /abc         | 1          |
| asd          | /abc/asd     | 2          |
| asd          | /asd         | 3          |
| boo          | /abc/asd/boo | 4          |
| hey          | /abc/asd/hey | 5          |
```

the request would consult this url for `/abc/asd` document

```
GET /rest/documents/2
```

So, now you have to provide users of your API with means to traverse your structure with little effort. That could be done by wrapping your response payload (document) into an object, containing additional traversal information, like this:

```
{
   data: { /* your document goes here */ },
   parent: {"abc": 1 },
   children: [ { "boo": 4 }, { "hey": 5} ]
}
```

provided that you expect users not to create too much documents in a single level, you can include a list of children into the response. If that's not the case you could offer user to retrieve child document IDs like so, allowing e.g. for paging the results via querystring parameters:

```
GET /rest/documents/2/children?page=2&size=50
```

Finally, speaking of querystring parameters, you could also supply the path information directly through the querystring parameters:

```
GET /rest/documents?path=somepath&page=1&size=42
```

All of the approaches mentioned expect that the plain `GET /rest/documents` returns only root documents.

Comment: Good idea. However, the relationship to the child documents is not clear from the API if the child docs are included in the response for a document. If documents also has another subresource, e.g. comments, you would typically access the questions for a document using /documents/{id}/questions. To be consistent and make the relationship to child documents clear in the API, I would suggest that child documents should be accessed by /documents/{id}/child-documents. The representations returned would be Documents just like /documents/{id}. So, the rest of what you described here still works also.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps:

```
/rest/{rootEntity}/Item/{leafEntity}/{id}
/rest/{entity}/ItemList
/rest/{entity}/ItemList/{leafEntity}
```

where {rootEntity} is the starting point of your collection, {leafEntity} is any named leaf node within your tree.

You could append a few parameters any of the above to select, say, Latest or All or something.